# sql query/sub query for finding students enrolled in specific program

Tags: sql, subquery, many-to-many, inner-join

I am working on intro SQL query questions. I have created the table. The table displays perfectly however I need help retrieving the following: Can you guide me on how I would solve such problems in the future.

1. Find the name of students who are enrolled in 'ITEC' programs.
2. Find the names of students who had been registered for at least 1 course

This is what I have.

```
/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE Student(sid integer PRIMARY KEY, sname text, yofb integer);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(50,'Dave', 1984);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(23,'Jones', 1993);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(53,'Smith', 1993);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(55,'Green', 1995);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(54,'Webb', 1980);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(57,'Brown', 1981);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(60,'Smith', 1979);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(62,'Moor', 1976);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(64,'Wolf', 1978);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES(58,'Potter', 1983);

/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE Transcript(sid integer, cid text, mark integer, PRIMARY KEY (sid, cid));

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(50,'IT1010', 86);
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(53,'IT1010', 45);
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(53,'CS3421', 89);
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(53,'IT1011', 91);
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(60,'IT1010', 85);
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(60,'BA2430', 86);
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(57,'BA2430', 45);
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(58,'CS4411', 89);
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(59,'IT1010', 91);
INSERT INTO Transcript VALUES(57,'IT1010', 85);

/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE Course(cid text, ctitle text, pcode text, PRIMARY KEY (cid));

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO Course VALUES('IT1010', 'Class 1', 'ITEC');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES('CS4411', 'Class 3', 'COSC');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES('IT1011', 'Class 2', 'ITEC');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES('CS3421', 'Class 3', 'COSC');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES('BA2430', 'Class 4', 'BART');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES('CS5511', 'Class 2', 'COSC');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES('MA3210', 'Class 3', 'MATH');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES('IT3210', 'Class 4', 'ITEC');

SELECT 
    s.sid, s.sname 
FROM
    Student s 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT c.cid FROM Course c 
            WHERE c.pcode = 'ITEC' AND c.cid = s.sid)
```

It's not really returning the name of students. And would love any suggestion on how I would deal with "at least 1, or more than 1 or less than 1" type of questions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is on the right track - but need to use bridge table `transcript` to then refer to `course`:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.sname 
FROM Student s 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Transcript t
    INNER JOIN Course c ON c.cid = t.cid
    WHERE c.pcode = 'ITEC' AND t.sid = s.sid
)
```